# Single connection per transaction vs single connection for all transactions?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, pymongo, psycopg2, database

Which database contact method is better? A single connection per transaction or a single connection for all transactions.

Comment: Search for connection pool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it depends on your use cases. Connection initialization may be costly process so you can avoid creating new connections for every single query for specific cases. However; the code below is a common best practice pattern for db query executions.

```
private int Execute(){
    using (var connection = new SqlConnetion()){
        var sql="Some query statement";
        var command = new SqlCommand (sql, connection);
        connection.open();

        var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // or ExecuteReader 
        return result;
    }   
}
```

After the execution leaves the scope, the connection and related resources are released thanks to using statement.